# Advanced Windows Application UI (MDI Tabbed Group)

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, visual-c++, mfc

I would like to be able to create an MDI UI layout that extends the behavior of [MDI Tabbed Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165830.aspx) in the following way.  Within a pane for a split tabbed group, I'd like to create a nested tab group with the opposite directional alignment.  For instance, given a horizontally split top level, I would like to create a vertically split tab group within the first pane.  This appears to necessitate a rework of the CMDIFrameWndEx and associated classes.

The Tabbed Group Layout is an appealing UI device.  It's a shame it's not available in mainstream web browsers.  Am I right in assuming that its best support is in the Visual  C++ Feature Pack?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.dotnetmagic.com/features_tabbedMDI.html) one example, at least.  Also, [AvalonDock](http://www.codeplex.com/AvalonDock).  I guess MFC remains a laggard in many respects.